# not able to make changes to the view in a viewpager

Tags: android

I am trying to make a viewpager for a book application. I took help from android turorial http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html and rest I am trying to do on my own. I am stuck at a point where a view change(changing textview text font on click) is not taking effect inside a page.

Some code here

activity_main.xml

> 

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleStory3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="@string/titleWeight"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStory3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="@string/contentTextViewWeight"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerStory3LinearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="@string/footerWeight"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footerStory3RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/PageCountStory3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="page count"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BookmarkTextViewStory3"
                android:layout_width="70sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="addBookmark"
                android:text="bookmark"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

as you can see there is textview "BookmarkTextViewStory3" where there is a method "addBookmark" attached on onClick. That is where i get stuck as I will explain later.

here is the activity_screen_slide.xml

in my code I have for "addMookmark" inside ny FragmentActivity class(besides the other code for pageadapter instance reation and others as in the tutorial).

> /** Called when the user clicks the "bookmark page/remove bookmark" link */

```
public void addBookmark(View view) {
            bookmarkPageTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);}
                        }
```

The changes to the textview(bookmarkPageTextView) are not happening when I click the textview. If I put  a Toast statement inside the method addBookmark then I can see the message popping up on emulator. Hence the code execution does seem to go inside the method. But the textview changes are not happening.

Any help here from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I just had to create a reference to the textview object. I had made it in the wrong place in my code. SO just had to add the line

> bookmarkPageTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BookmarkTextViewStory3);